# How can I create an OLAP data cube on AWS Aurora-postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, olap-cube

Our database is in Aurora Postgres on AWS. I access it using psycopg2 in python. The data is such that each row represents an instance of an item being brought. There areI multiple columns such as the time_when_sold, item_name, item_category, customer_name. I want to create a multi-dimensional data cube so that the data can be better organized and pre-aggregated, which would make query results faster too. However, I cannot figure out how to create the data cube on postgres. The online resources I've gone through don't seem to talk about postgres. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would say that Redshift is more OLAP oriented than Aurora.

Comment: Would I need to create a new db in Redshift and transfer the records over there from Aurora?

Comment: Redshift is an AWS separate service. It's OLAP oriented, unlike Aurora/PostgreSQL that is "replication, transactional oriented" service. They serve different purposes. And, yes, you'll need to export/import if you decide using Redshift.